The moment of weapon ownership transfer
As stated in this answer,

If Poland (for example) sends a gun, a tank, an airplane to Ukraine, the moment the Ukrainian army takes control of them; those are part of the Ukrainian army.

But when and where exactly is this moment?

This is going to depend on the agreement and there is no one answer that will work. But for your final answer they would still be attacking Poland itself regardless of the reasons Russia may claim.

@JoeW That's true, but, for example, Israel attacks "weapon supply convoys for Hezbollah" anywhere without consequences and USA itself used to assault "ships transferring weapons" in the Red Sea. German MoD Pistorius said that "attacks on supply routes in rearwards is legal" and Kuleba said then "Poland is an Ukrainian rearward" so it is not exactly "Russian claim" but a common opinion.

That is because the countries involved choose not to retaliate and Poland/NATO could choose to do nothing or they could choose to treat it as an act of war. It would all depend on what exactly gets hit by a hypothetical Russian attack. It doesn't matter if they only attack military equipment that belongs to Ukraine if they attack it at a base/area controlled by Poland and Poland treats it as an attack on Poland.

@user13964273 I don't think Israel attacks "weapon supply convoys for Hezbollah" is a particularly apt comparison.  Israel is not acting in a nukepower-on-nukepower context, as Russia would be doing with NATO.  Israel's actions receive frequent condemnation.  Israel is technically at war with Syria and has been shot at from Lebanese territory.  MoD Pistorius can talk tough, but he represents a country that is on the uber-handwringing side of military in-action.  Ask yourself:  if an active Russian warplane was in China, should Ukraine shoot it down there?

It's not clear that the same answer would apply for all purposes: taxation, insurance, export controls, legal liability, etc. In addition, a government may be able to impound goods on its territory even if they have another owner.

That likely depends on the conditions negotiated in these transferal agreements.
Like there are agreements like "nuclear sharing" in which ownership and control does not fully go over to the country hosting and even being trained on deployment of the nukes, as that would be in violation of the non-proliferation treaty. While in cases of buying, selling or gifting weapons, likely full ownership titles are transferred to the recipient.
When that happens, so on payment, already within the country transferring them to the recipient or at the border crossing or after they received their destination and given to the respective end users, is probably a matter of the agreements, which are likely not public.
Though as NATO does not wants to become a conflict party it is likely that they fully give up ownership of the weapons either as a gift or a trade agreement for which they are reimbursed otherwise. So that an attack upon those weapons is not considered an attack on a NATO member.
Though if Russia were to attack tanks in Poland, whether they were Polish, Ukrainian or of any other nationality, that would nonetheless be an attack on Polish soil and hence an attack on a NATO member triggering Article 5 defense protocols.
So no Russia can not legally do that, but more importantly than "legally" that would escalate that conflict way beyond Ukraine.


Israel attacks "weapon supply convoys for Hezbollah" anywhere without consequences

Not anywhere. In weak countries like Syria. Which even Russia only kinda helps. Also, Syria does complain to the UN. Even Israel's own strikes on Iran have been a bit more limited thus far. And Iran shot back albeit not very effectively. We'll see what happens after Trump takes office.
If Russia were to bomb weapon supplies headed for Ukraine inside a NATO country that country could well invoke article 5 instead of just complaining to the UN.
And Russia might find out that it could be on the losing end of a conventional war with NATO as a result. Or at least have its military severely degraded. And then what? Trigger nuclear winter?
Anyhow, Putin says that Russia has the right to strike Western & other countries that arm Ukraine.

"We consider ourselves entitled to use our weapons against the military facilities of those countries that allow their weapons to be used against our facilities," Putin said.

So, on paper, not that different from what Israel claims. But Russia has yet to exercised this right they claim.
FWTW, this claim is contradicted by the ICRC

Are arms supplying States considered to be parties to armed conflict?
Under IHL, a State does not become a party to an armed conflict on the sole ground that it supplies weapons or military equipment to a belligerent.
A State supplying arms to a State party to an international armed conflict becomes itself a party to that conflict if it resorts to armed force against another belligerent State, such as when it is effectively involved in military operations against that State.
A State supplying arms to a non-State armed group party to an armed conflict becomes itself a party to the conflict when it equips (with weapons for instance) and finances such group but also coordinates or helps in the general planning of its military activity, thereby exerting overall control over such group.

I'm sure Putin has his own extra arguments eroding that, like claiming Ukraine is puppet of the West/NATO etc. He's been saying that for the past 10 years or so.

"Or at least have its military severely degraded." Too late. That has already happened.

@ohwilleke: they still have most of their airforce. F-35s and/or F-22s could easily change that.


But when and where exactly is this moment?

The weapons are considered Ukraine's when the Ukrainian military has the weapons in their possession and can use them in military operations.
Weapons kept in Poland (or other countries) are not in Ukrainian control or possession. Even if Poland allows the Ukrainian military to come to Poland to take delivery of the weapons, they may have possession of the weapons, but can't realistically use them for military operations from Poland (since Poland will not allow any attack from Polish territories, against Russia, as it will draw Poland directly into conflict with Russia).
Similarly, any Russian attack on Poland (or other countries), to destroy the weapons being supplied to Ukraine, will be a huge military escalation and the attacked country can declare war against Russia.
Obviously, neither Russia, or Ukraine's allies, currently want any direct conflict with each other.
Another related example highlights this - everyone knows that some NATO countries are also training Ukrainian military personnels in their country. These Ukrainian troops can be legitimate targets for Russia. But Russia knows attacking these Ukrainian trainees in a foreign country can be perceived as an escalation that may widen the war. That is why it doesn't take such military actions.

Can Russian army legally hit Rzeszów claiming that Ukrainian weapons are stored there?

("Legally" is a tricky question as the world is still divided if the Russians had valid and reasonable justifications for militarily attacking Ukraine in the first place).
I'd say it's in the grey area, but mostly yes, considering previous international precedents.
As Russia is at war, theoretically it can take any military actions (short of a nuclear attack or crimes against humanity), against anyone, in self-defence. This includes military attacks against Ukraine's allies too, who are training the Ukrainian military and supplying it with weapons. But, as stated above, it would escalate and widen the war, as any attacked country will then have reasonable justification to also attack Russia. And if Russia cannot provide genuine proof (of assistance to bolster Ukraine's war effort), diplomatically, Russia's action would also earn it condemnation by the international community.
Past international precedents Russia can use to "justify" such attacks include:

Israel attacking Iran: Israel is purportedly at war with Hamas. It recently assassinated a Hamas leader in Iran recently. Iran retaliated with a missile attack on Israel. Israel then escalated and launched an air attack on Iran to bomb some supposedly nuclear and military targets. Both countries claim that they are willing to up the ante further, but so far, no further military confrontations has happened.

India attacking Pakistan: India launched a military attack on a terrorist training camp in Pakistan, after a terrorist attack on India. Pakistan in retaliation also launched a small-scale air strike in Indian territories. Both sides then decided to not escalate the issue.


There are numerous other such examples.
Note that "international" law during war time is itself a whole grey area, with "might" often dictating what is valid / reasonable / justified during war time. The powerful continue to make up the rules as it suits them.
Russia is definitely doing so, despite the opposition it faces from other superpowers.
Another current example is the political apathy of Israel's western allies - anyone with common sense and a basic understanding of human rights will recognize that when 70% of women and children are amongst the dead ("collateral damage") in Gaza  there is a clear indication of a war crime by the Israeli army (and state), if not an open genocide, that needs to be investigated by the international community. And yet, Israel's powerful western allies ensure that Israeli military and political leaders will never be held culpable for what is obviously a clear and continuing historical pattern of crimes against humanity since the inception of the State of Israel - the repeated culling of Palestinians, amidst the subsequent land grab of Palestinian territory, by the Israeli-right. Even as the international community repeatedly highlights its concerns (evident in the UN) that imperialism still hasn't been eradicated, and continues to thrive in the form of colonialism by the State of Israel, its western allies (some of whom are themselves former imperialists) blatantly ensure that nothing is done to change the political status quo of the region.
All these superpowers continue to  follow the ancient political dictum that "might is right". (Under such circumstances, who then can blame Ukrainians for aspiring for nuclear weapons?)

"Under such circumstances, who then can blame Ukrainians for aspiring for nuclear weapons?" - nuclear weapons aren't a universal shield. If they were, the USA and USSR would only have needed one each during the cold war. Where conflicting states differ in size and economic power, the larger would simply respond to the smaller with proliferation of weaponry and weapons technology that the smaller cannot match. The only stability is achieved when equal-sized regimes treat each other as peers, as the USA and USSR ultimately did.

IIRC in that incident Pakistan did bomb something in return https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Jammu_and_Kashmir_airstrikes Unless you're talking about some other event. But they might have missed their ground targets on purpose based on footage they released https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-4_SOW#Operational_history So, I guess there's that kind of de-escalation.

"Under such circumstances, who then can blame Ukrainians for aspiring for nuclear weapons?" Perhaps, the same people that blame Iran in developing nuclear weapon...

@264champagnebottlesonice I had forgotten that Pakistan did indeed retaliate with a limited air-strike. I've corrected my answer. Thanks.

In war, the law is really whatever the combatants or the victors say it is.
Russia can hit anywhere it likes. If it wins, it will declare it followed the law. If it loses, the West will declare its entire conduct illegal. The question of which side is to be master remains under adjudication as we speak.
The principle earlier in the war was that both sides would confine their hits to the former territory of Ukraine. This apparently suited both sides.
Now it seems to suit neither side to remain within such confines, therefore the hits may start occurring across a wider range of each others' territory from now on.
Trying to analyse forensically the moment of transfer is pointless, when the point is that the sides likely won't agree on the applicable law in the first place or it's application to the facts, and each reserves the right to decide the law in a trial by combat.
Also, Russia is likely to take a commonsense view about whether the materiel in question is destined to be used against it in some way. The moment at which the members of an enemy axis consider the materiel transferred amongst themselves is largely irrelevant to the question on the other side of dealing damage to them all together as an enemy collective.

This is nonsense.  It would be an attack on Polish territory, thus triggering NATO article 5.  Sure, if the war was fought and Russia magically won, they could retroactively declare it had been legal but so what?  Nothing in international customs allows for attacking inactive enemy troops on neutral territory (as opposed to the right of hot pursuit which would happen if say a Ukrainian plane tried to escape a dogfight by flying into Poland).

@ItalianPhilosopher, if the NATO members have already resolved to make Russia lose, then it's difficult to understand what the extra threat of triggering article 5 even is. Article 5 is only a deterrent if they're going to let Russia win, otherwise it's going to be total war anyway. Russia is not going to back down, because they all remember - government and citizens alike - the last time they let Western liberals collapse their state. As for neutral territory, Russia will of course judge that the NATO members are not neutral at all but part of the enemy collective they are fighting.

Are you saying there is no difference between NATO forces blowing Russia out of Ukraine and Western governments providing limited material support to Ukraine?

Also, are you saying that if Russia beats Ukraine, it can dictate the US and China what's legal?

@bharring, you mean if Russia beats the US in Ukraine? The reality is, Russia's success is equivalent to the US and China's acquiescence to the law it will have laid down for itself on this occasion. It will have dictated the verdict in its own trial.

"This apparently suited both sides." This is obviously false, since Ukraine has been attacking targets within Russia almost throughout the entire war. And they have been saying for a long time now that they would like to also do this with weapons supplied by Western countries. So obviously, this "principle" does not suite one of the two parties at war. (But of course you know this, just as you know that "the former territory of Ukraine" is simply the territory of Ukraine, without any "former".)

@JochenGlueck, yes but not with advanced technologies only Zelensky's backers possess (and which he never possessed independently). Putin would be hard faced to blame Biden or Donald Tusk for every drone bomb or howitzer blast Zelensky sends over.

Russia defeating the US, or even just Poland, in Ukraine is a pipedream. Nothing Russia has short of nuclear weapons would have a snowballs chance at facing either. They're barely able to handle Ukraine alone.

Putin would be hard pressed to claim there's any justification to invade Ukraine, but here we are. So that's not a strong argument.

"Zelensky's backers", "Zelensky sends over" You're projecting a very specific 'one man show' perspective on politics onto a different country.

@JochenGlueck, it's no different than I'm referring to Putin, Biden, or Tusk as "one man shows".

@Steve: Yepp, you're referring to four political systems (Russia, US, Poland, Ukraine) as one man shows, while only the first of them actually is one. As I said, you're projecting.

"Article 5 is only a deterrent if they [NATO] are going to let Russia win"  No, because there's a whole range of outcomes that don't classify as a Russian "win", ranging from withdrawal to 2020 borders, withdrawal to 2013 borders, with or without annihilation of the Russian armed forces, to forced regime change in Russia, forcing de-annexation of territory which goes back to groups other than Ukraine, all the way to dissolution of Russia as a sovereign entity and Balkanization of core Russia.  Proxy war is likely to reach very different outcomes than direct conflict with NATO.

@BenVoigt, another outcome that doesn't classify as Russian win, but also doesn't classify as Western win, is nuclear armageddon. If NATO is seriously willing to press the button to defend it's members' integrity, then why wouldn't Putin be, and I don't see how any of the outcomes you mention are consistent with Russian national integrity. If one holds that Russia can't afford to back down in Ukraine now, then NATO has the choice between total war with a nuclear power (perhaps because it cannot back down either, although many think Trump may back down quite casually), or NATO backing down.1/2

If total war is on the cards, then there's nothing to threaten Putin with, because anything you've actually got you're going to throw at him. Be realistic. Nobody thinks Putin or the Russian state could survive backing down in Ukraine. The worst fears of Ukraine's sponsors though, is that Trump not only will back down, but will benefit in the opinion polls from doing so. It's completely asymmetrical to consider what Trump and the USA now has at stake compared to what Putin and Russia has. And that's what will determine the outcome. (2/2)

You're confused if you think "withdrawal to 2020 borders, without destruction of Russian military" is "incompatible with Russian national integrity". Putin is not Russia, even though he acts like it. But even for Putin, stepping down from government is far superior to being shot in the back, which might happen if his inner circle become convinced that he's going to do something for egotistical reasons that gets them killed. Troops ordered to make an escalatory strike might refuse to avoid embroiling their families. So yeah, there are many ways this ends other than total war or Russian victory.

@BenVoigt, we all know enraged liberals wouldn't stop there, and the Russian state knows it too. I suspect China also needs Ukraine to be at least humbled, in order to set an example for Taiwan. Putin would have to at least eat a bullet to back down now. And the analysis I've heard is that his "inner circle" are even more radical. In terms of troops disobeying, it sounds like wishful thinking - you're either escalating gradually when some soldiers' families have already been destroyed, or you're responding all-out to incoming armageddon where you can be the last vengeance for your family.

"The worst fears of Ukraine's sponsors though" Maybe you should refrain from speaking for people you refuse to understand.

It's funny to say "enraged liberals" wouldn't stop at defending Ukraine, especially when pretending they don't actually think Putin wouldn't stop with subjugation Ukraine. Only one side has invaded the other.
